# jQuery Mobile Loading Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am trying to make a mobile application using jQuery. I am using to make a swipe panel and i have a source for it. The sources are .html .css and .js the html and css seem to work but the .js does not. Any answers?

Its suppose to look like this [this](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/examples/panels/panel-swipe-open.html#demo-page)

Also its on my local web server.

**Source Code:**

.js

```
$(document).on("pageinit", "#demo-page", function () {
  $(document).on("swipeleft swiperight", "#demo-page", function (e) {
// We check if there is no open panel on the page because otherwise
// a swipe to close the left panel would also open the right panel (and v.v.).
// We do this by checking the data that the framework stores on the page element (panel: open).
    if ($.mobile.activePage.jqmData("panel") !== "open") {
      if (e.type === "swipeleft") {
        $("#right-panel").panel("open");
      }
      else if (e.type === "swiperight") {
        $("#left-panel").panel("open");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Are you adding the jquery library's before the script above?

Comment: Asuming you mean the jquery.mobile.custom.js library

Comment: You need to include links to the jquery and jquery mobile libarys

Comment: The are included in the html file

Comment: Like this:
<script src="link to jquery"></script><script src="link to jquery-mobile  "></script>

Comment: Indeed.

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"> </script><script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: Are their any errors in Chrome devtools (in chrome press f12, then go to the console tab)

Comment: Nope all scripts have 0 errors.

Comment: Are you including the jquery mobile css?

Comment: yes i am i am including jQuery and jQuery mobile.

Comment: add your html markup pls. Are you using a single-html file template or multi file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load your JS files in this order:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

reference: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html